# Is it possible to configure custom application records to work with the delievered Population Update process (App Engine: SCC_POP_UPD)?

Tags: peoplesoft

Simply - we have a custom application record that is loaded via File Parser, we want to be able to update one field for certain rows in that table as a part of a business process.

I added that table to to the underlying Population Update records but it will not not let me run the process from PIA. The Population Selection dropdowns are disabled on the run control page.

I am not certain if I should go through with this solution, or find some other way to update that record accordingly (custom app engine, etc...)

Any help would be appreciated.